# StringsR - catch correct numbers

Tags: r, regex, stringr, grepl

I am trying to perform string filtering based on R.
I have multiple hierarchies and I need to group them together

I have prepared an example:

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

numbers <- tibble(LEVEL = c('0.1', '0.1.1', '0.1.2', '0.11', '0.12', '0.11.1', '0.12.1', '0.12.2'))



# Return also different values - first shall only contained: 0.1, 0.1.1, 0.1.2
numbers %>% 
  filter(grepl("^0.1.?", LEVEL))


# Second shall only contained: 0.11, 0.11.1
# Third shall only contained: 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.12.2
```

String pattern I have used in grepl is not enough.

Comment: could you please elaborate more for your example? what you are trying to achieve? with example and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex patterns can be formulated in a more concise way:

```
numbers %>% 
  filter(grepl("^0\\.1$|^0\\.1\\.", LEVEL))   # 0.1, 0.1.1, 0.1.2
numbers %>% 
  filter(grepl("^0\\.11$|^0\\.11\\.", LEVEL)) # 0.11, 0.11.1
numbers %>% 
  filter(grepl("^0\\.12$|^0\\.12\\.", LEVEL)) # 0.12, 0.12.1, 0.12.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You were right, the regex pattern you supplied is not enough to extract the numbers as you want it.

The following code is probably what you are looking for.

```
numbers %>% 
filter(grepl("^[0]{1}\\.[1]{1}$|^[0]{1}\\.[1]{1}\\.", LEVEL))
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  LEVEL
  <chr>
1 0.1  
2 0.1.1
3 0.1.2
```

Next we want only `0.11, 0.11.1`, i.e. the number after the first has two 1s and then might be followed by another dot. We modify the code above to accomodate that change.

```
numbers %>% 
filter(grepl("^[0]{1}\\.(11){1}$|^[0]{1}\\.(11){1}\\.", LEVEL))
```

Here, we put the number `11` that we want to isolate into a group that is looked for to happen exactly once `{1}`. Similarly, we can write

```
numbers %>% 
filter(grepl("^[0]{1}\\.(12){1}$|^[0]{1}\\.(12){1}\\.", LEVEL))
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  LEVEL 
  <chr> 
1 0.12  
2 0.12.1
3 0.12.2
```

to get those with pattern `12`.